# SymbolsSource failing push to the new packages

Tags: symbols, symbol-server

I have created a symbolssource that is being used for a while already.

If I try to push packages generated in the old VS, it pushes the packages correctly, if I try to push new packages I got this error:

> nuget push *.symbols.nupkg 123 -Source http://localhost:3182/NuGet
>   Empurrando MYPACKAGE para 'http://localhost:3182/NuGet' ... Failed to
>   process request. 'Package submission failed: Unknown custom metadata
>   item kind: 6. See http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Home/Help for
>   possible reasons. Fiddler may help diagnosing this error if your
>   client discards attached detailed information.'.

I tried to update the symbolssource with the latest nuget packages, but still I have the same issue.

Comment: Funny is that it work for some packages and for other no, and it's related to the assembly being added. If I try another dll it works normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was the MSBuild 14 with the pdb metadata. There is a fix for it in this [link.](https://github.com/SymbolSource/SymbolSource.Community/issues/32)